# Videoview in samsung tablet 2 show black background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-videoview

> I can play video using videoview widget in phone and it's work no any
>   error reported to me.When i am going to test same build run in samsung
>   tablet 2 os 4.1 it's not render video in top of view and i am unable
>   to watch video .
>
> I settled text over videoview to watch at run time and i am able to
>   watch text over video but not video :(.

**Can you give a case of possiblity would be happen** and what is wrong with tablet .Thanks in advance.